# how to pass value using segue to show different web view in ios objective c

Tags: ios

I have two web views in home tab which is home web view and login web view.I would like to pass value from login tab to home tab if I pressed login button action using segue.

If I pressed login button,I would like to go login web view and if not,I would like to show normal home web view.I created segue to pass value.But it doesn't pass.

My segue login button identifier is "loginsegue".

**piece of my code viewcontroller.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
if([self.urlString isEqualToString:@"loginbtn"]){
        NSLog(@"login button pressed");
         [self loginCompleted];//call webview url from method
     }else{

         NSLog(@"home button pressed");
         [self homeCompleted];//call webview url from method
    }

}
    - (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    ViewController * target = segue.destinationViewController;
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"loginsegue"]) {
        target.urlString = @"loginbtn";
    }
 }
```

Comment: whats your questiion now

Comment: Can you show me screen shot for you storyboard ?
Because viewDidLoad will not fire after loading the view controller for the first time, so to understand you problem i want to see screen shot of your storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't mentioned how you are loading home page. Sample i have used login button segue.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if([self.urlString isEqualToString:@"loginbtn"]){
        NSLog(@"login button pressed");
        [self performSeguewithidetifier@"loginsegue"];
     }else{
        NSLog(@"home button pressed");
        [self performSeguewithidetifier@"loginsegue"];
    }

}
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    ViewController * target = (ViewController*) segue.destinationViewController;
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"loginsegue"]) {
        if([self.urlString isEqualToString:@"loginbtn"]){
            target.urlString = @"LoginPageURL";
        }
        else{
            target.urlString = @"homePageURL";
        }

    }
 }
```